# SQL Server :Substracting 2nd row from 1st ,3rd row from 2nd etc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling with an algorithm in SQL server , and I have no clue how to solve this . 
I have a column with timestamps on which I've ordered by desc .

I need to find out the differences between de 2nd row and the 1st , the 3rd row and the 2 nd as so on and display this in a new row .The final table should look like this :

```
ID                        Type                 Time_Stamp      Difference

xxx                       YYY                  00:03:12          00:00:02
xxx                       ZZZ                  00:03:14          00:00:02
xxx                       ZZZ                  00:03:16
```

Can I use some kind of SQL function ? Please let me know if you have any ideas .

Cheers ,

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Window Function`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY time_stamp) rn,
                *
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Type,
       a.Time_Stamp,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Datediff(second, a.Time_Stamp, b.Time_Stamp)/3600)
       + ':'
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (Datediff(second, a.Time_Stamp, b.Time_Stamp)%3600)/60), 2)
       + ':'
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(second, a.Time_Stamp, b.Time_Stamp)%60), 2) AS [Difference]
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.rn = b.rn - 1
```

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` then use `Lead` Function

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Datediff(second, time_stamp, Lead(time_stamp)
                                               OVER(
                                                 ORDER BY time_stamp)) AS Sec
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Type,
       a.Time_Stamp,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), sec/3600) + ':'
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (sec%3600)/60), 2)
       + ':'
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), sec%60), 2) AS [Difference]
FROM   cte a
```

**Update :** To insert into `temp table` do this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY time_stamp) rn,
                *
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Type,
       a.Time_Stamp,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Datediff(second, a.Time_Stamp, b.Time_Stamp)/3600)
       + ':'
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (Datediff(second, a.Time_Stamp, b.Time_Stamp)%3600)/60), 2)
       + ':'
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(second, a.Time_Stamp, b.Time_Stamp)%60), 2) AS [Difference] 
into #tempTable    --Here you need to use into temptable
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.rn = b.rn - 1
```

or `create` the temp table and use

```
......
 Insert into #temptable
 SELECT a.ID,
           a.Type,
           a.Time_Stamp
......
```

Comment: Yes it does the job but I still have a question , how can I insert the data from the query into a #tempTable ?

Answer (score 1):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID VARCHAR(10),[TYPE] VARCHAR(10),TIME_STAMP TIME)

INSERT INTO #TEMP

SELECT 'xxx' ,                      'YYY',                  '00:03:12'   
UNION ALL      
SELECT 'xxx',                       'ZZZ',                  '00:03:14' 
UNION ALL       
SELECT 'xxx',                       'ZZZ',                  '00:03:16'
```

You need to do self join logic to get next row's record

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY TIME_STAMP)RNO,*
    FROM #TEMP
)
SELECT C1.*,'00:00:'+CAST(DATEDIFF(S,C1.TIME_STAMP,C2.TIME_STAMP)AS VARCHAR(2)) D
FROM CTE C1 
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/467e8/1) to view result